# Importing parse library to Android Studio, gradle errors?

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle

"The project may be using a version of Gradle that does not support this method"

"The build file may be missing a gradle plugin"

In the upper level build.gradle I have

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

I also added the parse library to the lib folder and clicked on "Add to library" for all the `.jar` files.  After doing so, the other build.gradle says

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/bolts-android-1.2.0-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
}
```

I've looked at other SO posts, but I'm still not sure what else I am missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be adding the dependencies in the wrong build.gradle file. You should add it in the file which is at the same level as your libs directory(In project view).

It should look something like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.redux.example.quiz"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
              }

     buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                   }
                }
     }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

So just add the below given dependencies in the other build.gradle file. Make sure that you have deleted all the misplaced dependencies as they will not allow the build to complete.

```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    }
```

A video demo of setting up Parse.com for android can be found here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvKe3MxKA7I

Comment: Ok, that fixed that error, but now I'm getting something new

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing the library and re-adding the .lib files

Comment: I've been experimenting for hours and it still doesn't work. However, i experienced exactly the same errors as you did. Can you shortly explain what you did? What did you remove and where did you remove it from? What does "re-adding" mean to you? Copy the *.jar files again into the "libs" folder?

Comment: My problem was I had two versions of this Parse Facebook Plugin in the same dir. (v3 and v4) Deleted one (I believe it was v3) and it immediatly worked ;)